# The suitable reletiviser in this sentence

Tags: relative-clauses

I wrote:

> It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes, **one of which is the current node**, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.

But I feel there is a pause and fragment for the relative clause. Could I write it as:

> - It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes, **of which one is the current node**, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.
> - It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes, **from which one is the current node**, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.
> - It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle node **where  one of them** is the current node, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.

Are they all correct? which are better?

Comment: Stick to **one of which** or **of which one**.  The alternatives are not improvements but the opposite. But **one or few** is not grammatical.  "... will be found *in the first few levels* directly above the current node in the DOM tree".

Comment: *It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes, from which one is the current node, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.*
Sounds better to me, since there are few options that may be the current node: "any two handle nodes", 'from which' refers to those options, and implies to say that one of them may be the current node.

Comment: Clearer: *... nodes, where one is the... .* Or *when one is the* or *nodes, one of them being the...* or *given one of them is the.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would rank the four options you give in this order of preference:

> 1. It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes, **one of which is the current node**, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.
> 2. It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes, **of which one is the current node**, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.
> 3. It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes, **from which one is the current node**, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.
> 4. It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes **where  one of them** is the current node, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.

However, I would probably rewrite this to make it clearer and easier to read as something like:

> Given any two handle nodes - one of which is the current node - it's supposed that their immediate ancestor is one or few levels up the DOM-tree.

This removes the ambiguity around the fragment and in my opinion flows a little more smoothly.

Comment: Thanks, how about *It’s supposed that the immediate ancestor of any two handle nodes, [where] one is the current node, is one or few levels up in the DOM-tree.*

Comment: Sure, I think that would be fine too, I'd put alongside the top 2 in my list above, equally good in my opinion. I still feel hyphens segregate the fragment in a more readable way than commas, but that's just my preference and perhaps others will point out some reason why this is worse than commas.